# SQL(MySQL): Fix ID column & AUTO INCREMENT

Tags: sql, mysql

I've a table with ID column, auto increment. Because of the bad migration a while a go, and I only noticed this now, form entries were all stored as ID 0. So now I have two problems: around 1000 entries with 0 as ID as well as column definition and AUTO INCREMENT value.

Latter is an easy fix, and I'm not concerned about that. But, is there a SQL command that I can use to programmatically fix IDs so that they're set just as if the AUTO INCREMENT was working properly the whole time.

The last `proper` id is 2540. After that entry, all the entries have id 0. There's 3200 rows in the table. So, all in all, I want to fix the table ID column so that all the IDs 0 are changed from 2541 to 3200. NOTE: I can't afford to change the old working IDs.

Comment: Did you set autoincrement column as primary key? Please provide table DDL and test data

Comment: What MySQL version you have?

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev MySQL 8

Comment: 'was working properly the whole time.' you can allocate an id but it won't necessarily reflect the order of events since data is stored in no particular order. Do you have something which would help?

Comment: *around 1000 entries with 0 as ID as well as column definition and AUTO INCREMENT value.* Do you want to say that you have a table on MySQL 8.0 in which the column `id` is AUTO_INCREMENT, and it is not a primary key but only a prefix of a primary key?

Comment: *I can't afford to change the old working IDs.* Provide complete CREATE TABLE script of the table. Provide any expression which does not include `id` column but is unique over the table.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a demo:

```
mysql> select * from mytable order by created_at;
+------+---------------------+
| id   | created_at          |
+------+---------------------+
| 2539 | 2023-10-23 09:58:00 |
| 2540 | 2023-10-23 09:59:00 |
|    0 | 2023-10-23 10:00:00 |
|    0 | 2023-10-23 10:01:00 |
|    0 | 2023-10-23 10:02:00 |
|    0 | 2023-10-23 10:03:00 |
|    0 | 2023-10-23 10:04:00 |
|    0 | 2023-10-23 10:05:00 |
+------+---------------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> set @id = 2540;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> update mytable set id = (@id := @id + 1) where id = 0 order by created_at;
Query OK, 6 rows affected, 1 warning (0.01 sec)
Rows matched: 6  Changed: 6  Warnings: 1
```

The use of user-defined variables in this way is discouraged and gives a warning, but at least in MySQL 8.0 it still works (I tested the above on MySQL 8.1.0).

> Warning 1287 Setting user variables within expressions is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Consider alternatives: 'SET variable=expression, ...', or 'SELECT expression(s) INTO variables(s)'.

You can then verify that the rows have been updated the way you want.

```
mysql> select * from mytable order by created_at;
+------+---------------------+
| id   | created_at          |
+------+---------------------+
| 2539 | 2023-10-23 09:58:00 |
| 2540 | 2023-10-23 09:59:00 |
| 2541 | 2023-10-23 10:00:00 |
| 2542 | 2023-10-23 10:01:00 |
| 2543 | 2023-10-23 10:02:00 |
| 2544 | 2023-10-23 10:03:00 |
| 2545 | 2023-10-23 10:04:00 |
| 2546 | 2023-10-23 10:05:00 |
+------+---------------------+
```

You should change `id` to be a primary key, then it won't allow duplicates.

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
```

You should also make sure your `sql_mode` option does NOT include `NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO`. If you insert a 0 value to an auto-increment column, it should generate a new incremented value.

Answer (score 1):

In case if you can reset ALL id values you can simply drop the id column and re-create it with right configuration:

```
alter table t drop column id;

alter table t add column id int primary key auto_increment first;
```

test solution [here](https://sqlize.online/sql/mysql57/1123606b8d2ec131016d2500b4ed6e5c/)

Another way - create procedure that fix table rows one by one:

```
delimiter $$
CREATE PROCEDURE fix_id()
BEGIN
  DECLARE _v INT;
  DECLARE _id INT;
  
  SELECT count(*) into _v FROM t WHERE id = 0;
  WHILE _v > 0 DO
    SELECT max(id) + 1 INTO _id FROM t;
    
    UPDATE t SET id = _id WHERE id = 0 LIMIT 1;
    
    SELECT count(*) INTO _v FROM t WHERE id = 0;
  END WHILE;
END;

delimiter ;

CALL fix_id();

select * from t;
```

test [here](https://sqlize.online/sql/mysql57/5a326e17cfb6f5724bbf56375cf34819/)

Don't forget to set column auto_incremet and primary key after update:

```
ALTER TABLE t MODIFY COLUMN id INT auto_increment primary key;
```